# Netbeans7.1 & JavaFX 2.0 - FXML code completion doesn't work

Tags: autocomplete, netbeans-7, javafx-2, fxml

I started learning JavaFX 2.0 and installed Netbeans 7.1, java 7.02 SDK (wich contains JavaFX 2). Everything seems to work, the example projects compile and run fine.

My problem is: Code completition doesn't work for FXML files. I press ctrl+space and it shows "No suggestions" every time. The same for tags and attributes.

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: There is a bug filed in Netbeans, http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=204741.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still show autocomplete menu for attributes by pointing the cursor just beginning (or middle to show sublist) of the existing attribute and hitting ctrl+space. Also while writing tags, Netbeans suggests even automatically puts closing tags for you. At any point in the FXML file, if you see "No suggestions", just hit "Esc" and try again actions mentioned above :).

[image: netbeans]

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that.It's better then nothing, I suppose. I hope they will fix this sometime, it's really a pain in the ass.