# Netbeans 8.2 autocomplete for FXML document is always showing "No suggestions"

Tags: netbeans, autocomplete, fxml, netbeans-8

I created a JavaFX project in Netbeans 8.2 for the first time and autocomplete for FXML document is always showing "No suggestions". For example:

[image]

I have seen a similar question, e.g. [Netbeans7.1 & JavaFX 2.0 - FXML code completion doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627163/netbeans7-1-javafx-2-0-fxml-code-completion-doesnt-work), but I am not getting the same results from the solution proposed there (possibly because the version of Netbeans is different). What do I need to do to get autocomplete in FXML documents? Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem running NetBeans 8.2 with jdk8u74. Selecting Source->Complete Code or using Ctrl + Space displays "No suggestions".  I do not have any errors in the IDE log. My Java Platform Manager - Javadoc is pointing to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api. The NetBeans code suggestions for .java file work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun I installed Netbeans 8.1 for Java SE alongside of version 8.2. The code completion for .fxml files works perfectly in 8.1. I'm going to try the development version next.

Right now I am calling this bug in Netbeans 8.2. I'll create a bug report when I get a chance.

Comment: Did you get that chance yet?  code completion for .fxml files still doesn't work.

Comment: there is an open bug report for this (271048) but I just installed NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201609300101) and the .fxml code completion is working again