# Why editing hibernate mapping xml no Classes are visible?

Tags: xml, hibernate, netbeans, mapping

I just upgraded netbeans 7.4 to 8.2 and it occurs that some features I used to disappeared. My project uses hibernate 3.6.10.
While editing `*.hbm.xml` files manually, it seems editor lost its ability to render project classes, when pressing Ctrl + Space

[image: no Suggestion]

project structure is the same, `hiberane.cfg.xml` in its right place (default package)

It looks like some features in NB 8.2 are set OFF

In previous IDE version(7.4) the behavior was like this:

[image: no Suggestion]:

I'm very eager to find out the reason and fix the problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Here is solution that does-not work for me anyway
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41931847/netbeans-8-2-autocomplete-for-fxml-document-is-always-showing-no-suggestions

there is an open bug report for this (271048) but I just installed NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201609300101) and the .fxml code completion is working again – choff Mar 2 '18 at 6:04

I have allready choff talk about. But the problem is not fixed

Comment: However I find the latest dev build, install it and took its url for Configuration or Update Center
http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/nbms-and-javadoc/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/nbbuild/nbms/updates.xml.gz/
Add it to my netbeans 8.2 IDE, checked and installed updates.
And problem had gone